# Can we add a wildcard in cognito callback url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I wanted to check if its possible to set wildcards in callback url's of Cognito.
Eg: Is it possible to keep wildcard for url like https://example.com/test/* instead of having multiple url's( https://example.com/test/explore , https://example.com/test/data)?

If yes, what would be syntax to do this?

Comment: As I know. `AWS Congnito` doesn't support wildcard callback URLs for security reasons.